# How do you prove that σ(1) + σ(2) + · · · + σ(n) ≤ n^2 for each positive integer n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I fix positive integers n and k with 1 ≤ k ≤ n, I need to figure first out for which integers i with 1≤i≤n is k a term in the sum that defines σ(i) and how many such integers i are there (phrased differently: how many times does k occur in the sum σ(1) + σ(2) + · · · + σ(n) if you write each σ(i) as a sum?)? I know the answer depends on n and k but I can't figure out how to do the proof for the original question without first figuring out this step.

Comment: Just for clarity: $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors functions, right?

Comment: yes \sigma is the sum of divisors

Answer (score 0):

Fix a positive integer $n$.

For each positive integer $k$, there are exactly $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ elements of $\{1,...,n\}$ which are multiples of $k$, hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(i)&=\sum_{k=1}^n k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\\[4pt]
&\le\sum_{k=1}^n k{\,\cdot\,}\frac{n}{k}\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^n n\\[4pt]
&=n^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}